# How to implement interactive design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, animation, dynamic

I want to implement the following design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1vDB.png)

On the tap first the bulb should glow and go to the right and wire length extends. Then there will be some widgets should be shown like plus icon button and on press there should be some dialog to get data like text and on confirmation, the text should be annotated properly on the place where the button was pressed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwRuf.png)

What would be the ideal way to pull this design in a scalable manner?

Comment: I suggest you learn more about CustomPainter for the bulb and its animation